# Add new Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Ao adicionar um novo `Controller` em meu projeto usando a opção `MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework` estou tendo o erro `there was an error running the selected code generator`, conforme a imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ele está dizendo que você já criou um controller para esse objeto, não seria isso?

Comment: não existe o controller ainda

Comment: Você tá usando o evento `OnModelCreating` pra configurar alguma coisa do *Model*?

Comment: Sim estou usando `Fluent API`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974218/scaffolding-controller-doesnt-work-with-visual-studio-2013-update-3-and-4) parece ser exatamente o mesmo problema que você encontrou.

A sugestão (que, segundo o autor da pergunta, funcionou pra ele também) foi adicionar a seguinte configuração no *OnModelCreating*:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderConfiguration());
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de criar o *Controller*, ceritifique-se de que não exista uma linha com algo assim no evento `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UsuarioConfiguration());
```

Comment: Sim existe, então eu não poderia usar `Fluent API`? pra fazer o mapeamento das entidades com o EF

Comment: @PabloVargas Até pode, mas esteja ciente de que o Scaffolding não trabalha bem com Fluent API.